# Is there a way to keep hardy geraniums upright?

Tags: rain, geraniums

I have some large hardy geraniums in my yard. At their best, they are about 2 feet tall and look beautiful.

[image]

However, after a storm, they flatten out and do not look nice:

[image]

We get heavy storms frequently this time of year, so the flattening happens every year. The plants do not bounce back; once they are on the ground, they stay there.

Is there any way to prevent my geraniums from flattening in the event of a storm? And if not, are there any tricks for making them look appealing again?

Answer (score 4):

I only do this for peonies, but I don't see why it wouldn't work for geraniums.

Stake around the plot (whatever sort of "garden stake" you typically use should be fine.) Tie string around the perimeter, and for large clumps, criss-cross through the middle as well. For taller plants, it is sometimes helpful to run two or more levels of strings. The strings can be placed and the plants allowed to grow up through them, or you can work the strings through the plants.

The garden-industrial-complex also offers steel grids for the purpose.

Answer (score 4):

I found this alternate solution that might be easier, less visible, and possibly more attractive. (That is, if your geraniums have not already grown too tall for this to be feasible this year. Of course, then it won't work.)

From the link: "This rather poor photo shows how I support a hardy geranium (G. sanguineum) with a simple tunnel of bent wire mesh placed over the plant before growth start."

[image]
[Source](https://gardenchitchat.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/003.jpg)

(I offered another answer, and I liked Ecnerwal's answer, too. It's a different answer, and so I was not sure whether to just edit my other answer or post a new answer.)

Comment: Diane Thank you for both answers, and @Ecnerwal for yours, too! I think putting the two as separate answers is perfect. I've given a +1 to all three, but it will be hard to choose one as the best. I have 6 of these geraniums in the front. I think I'll try the 2 staking and twining ideas this year, since they're already quite tall, and try this idea and the peony ring idea in the spring, because I think they are already too tall to put something like this in place. Thank you! I don't know how I will pick one answer to accept on this one!

Comment: Michelle- lol I think you should post what you just said here, as your answer, and accept it as the answer! I'll vote for it! And why not? It really is a combination answer. Glad we were helpful. ;)

Comment: Truly, I won't be offended if you accept @Ecnerwal' s answer, at all. I liked it, and that's why I voted for it, too!

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if this "Flexible Tie" would work for you. It's really useful! Very bendable, and has a really soft rubber coating that doesn't cut into plant stems. It's almost like a stronger, longer version of a twist tie, and you can re- bend it quite a bit without the inner wire breaking. You could use something a little more rigid for low stakes, and then loosely loop this stuff around in the middle of the plants to offer support where the green color will blend in, without it being unsightly.

It's available near me at The Dollar Store, in VA, USA. It's really inexpensive, and there is a lot on the roll to experiment with. I don't know where you live, so you might have to look online to find a place that sells it near you. 
(And, if it doesn't work for your geraniums, it would still be useful to tie up other plants, shrubs and trees.)

[image: flexible tie]

Comment: That is nice stuff for plant ties.  Just an aside, most plants do not need support.  To tie up plants, give branches support or staking trees, the plant relies on the support and gets weak, sort of like a cast on your arm?  When you take it off the muscles have atrophied?  Fruiting vegetables on vines like indeterminate tomatoes, cucumbers, peas I always tie and support and train.  I only stake bare root trees until they become established in a few months.  But to have regular storms or high wind that makes a difference...this cage is a wonderful idea.